# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS courses;

USE courses

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teachers(
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VAR_CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    addr VAR_CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    phone INT NOT NULL,
);
```

When I run it, I get an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'VAR_CHAR(50) NOT NULL, addr VAR_CHAR(255) NOT
NULL, phone INT NOT NULL, )' at line 3
```

Comment: it's `VARCHAR` not `VAR_CHAR`!

Comment: Thank you! Just a simple error )

Comment: MySQL gives the same error code regardless of which error in SQL is it? I wish the error code was closely related to the type of error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is `varchar` and not `var_char`

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS courses;

USE courses;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teachers(
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    addr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    phone INT NOT NULL
);
```

You should use a SQL tool to visualize possbile errors like *MySQL Workbench*.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't accept using reserved words such as 'name' on column names.

Therefore, to avoid this problem you could use back-ticks(`). This way, MySQL will treat them as column names rather than reserved keywords.

Try this:

Use back-ticks for NAME

```
CREATE TABLE `teachers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: what's the use of back-ticks?

Comment: Backticks tell MySQL that the thing within them is the name of something and not a special reserved word. Otherwise imagine the problems you would face if you had a table called `select` or `from`.

Answer (score 0):

Use varchar instead of VAR_CHAR and omit the comma in the last line i.e.phone INT NOT NULL
);. The last line during creating table is kept "comma free".
Ex:- CREATE TABLE COMPUTER
(
Model varchar(50)
);
Here, since we have only one column ,that's why there is no comma used during entire code.