# Syntax Error in MySQL on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, sql, text, syntax

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that coresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 4

```
CREATE TABLE esk (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
UserID INT,
FileID INT,
Key TEXT);
```

Where is the error?
Server version is 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: I'm thinking that "TEXT" is wrong, but this version is said to support TEXT, since it's not new, and TEXT has no variable indicating its length. I'm lost.

Comment: I did just now, no clue still. Thanks a lot for help though!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742492/error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KEY is a reserved key word

use ` back ticks

```
CREATE TABLE esk (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
UserID INT,
FileID INT,
`Key` TEXT);
```